# How do I run a method from a relative ViewModel and get its return value?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui, avaloniaui

To better show my problem, I drew a graph of how my ViewModel hierarchy looks like so far:

[ViewModel hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NTT3.png)

What I want to achieve is simply call a method from **ScriptEditorViewModel** and ask it, if the object, which is currently being edited inside **EditObjectViewModel** has been specified in the script.
Later I also want to send some information to **ScriptEditorViewModel** and make it generate a script for the object if it doesn't exist.

**ScriptEditorViewModel** and **ProjectManagementViewModel** are 2 separate tabs in my program, which are basically operating at the same time.

Is it possible to do that and if so, is it a good approach?

Note: I'm currently using ReactiveUI as my MVVM framework but any other MVVM solution is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MVVM pattern, you want to decouple components.

- In View part there is xaml with bindings to data and command present in ViewModel.
- In ViewModel you should keep data that is presented and logic that does something with that data. It is not the wisest thing to couple multiple ViewModels - keep their logic separated. If you have a command method, all data it deals with should be present in its ViewModel. For anything more complex, you shoud consider communicating with some kind of service or database.
- Hence comes the Model part. Here you want to create the model of something you want to store and not necessary present in a View.

I don't know if I understood your problem well, but including a database or any kind of  'persistence layer' into your solution should resolve the problem of accessing specific information. You can create some in-memory storage for start.

Comment: I understand, but what when I need the same data in multiple ViewModels and have it updated dynamically? In my case it's a class, which is created at the start of the program (Project.cs). Is constant saving and re-reading an approach I should take in this case?

Comment: Well yes, databases are used for both long-term storage of mostly passive data, and dynamic data that change a lot. In-memory dbs are usually used for latter.

Comment: Start with something simple like a class with static Dictionary and CRUD methods. Build on from there. You can replace it with some real db later.

Comment: Worth noting that reactiveui navigation does have the ability to send parameters to a subsequent view model. Especially if you use sextant. This will achieve the separation that @redcrusaderjr recommended